# How should I run this query in SQL?

Tags: php, sql, sql-order-by

I have table of likes/dislikes on game: id, game_id, type(like/dislike), time

Table example: Image Link

This code gives me the last week games the had likes, order by their likes count:

```
$limit = 10;
$time = _time() - 60*60*24*7;
$games_id = array();
$games_id_query = $this->db->execQuery("SELECT `game_id`, count(*) as `likes_count` FROM `likes` WHERE `type` = 'like' AND `time` > '{$time}' group by `game_id` order by `likes_count` DESC LIMIT {$limit}");
$games_id_num = $games_id_query->num_rows;
if($games_id_num > 0) {
    while($row = $games_id_query->fetch_object()) {
        unset($row->likes_count);
        $games_id[] = (array) $row;
    }
}
```

I want to make this query, to be order by ONLY the likes that get in the last week.

Example: If game X have 5 likes, and game Y have 6 likes, but game X get THIS WEEK 3 likes, and game Y get THIS WEEK 2 likes - Game X Would Be First and Game Y Would Be Second.

Thanks you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Add a column for week and order it by that column in desc order.

Something like this

```
SELECT game_id
       ,DATEPART(wk, likeDate)
       ,count(*) as `likes_count`
FROM   likes 
WHERE  typ = 'like' 
AND    time > '{$time}' 
group by
       game_id
       ,DATEPART(wk, likeDate)
order by 
       2 DESC 
LIMIT  {$limit}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you did here ? I don't know what is datepart, and what is order by 2

Comment: Datepart takes out the week/year/day from any date. And order by 2 is order the results by second column. You can try this in simple select 
like for week `Select DatePart(wk, getdate())` for year `Select Datepart(yy,getdate())`

Comment: What results do you get? Can you post the expected and actual results?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a CASE:

```
SELECT `game_id`, COUNT(*) AS `likes_count` 
FROM `likes` 
WHERE `TYPE` = 'like' AND `TIME` > '{$time}' 
GROUP BY `game_id` 
ORDER BY COUNT(CASE WHEN `TIME` >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '7' DAY END) DESC 
LIMIT {$limit}
```

Your DBMS seems to be MySQL, afaik it supports both INTERVAL arithmetic and calculations in ORDER.

Comment: Ok, i see. Your query already returns the counts of the last week based on $time. What do you want, the count of all likes but sorted be last weeks likes? Then simply remove the AND `time` > '{$time}' from the WHERE condition.